# Creating a button to delete data from table in qt

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt, delete-row

Using mysql and python, I have created a table within PyQt that will allow a user to frequently update and track their meeting sessions. The only problem is, I do not know how I would go about coding a button that will allow me to individually delete a row of data.

My table looks like so:

[image]

What would be the simplest way to create a button that will appear besides the row of data when new data is inserted that will allow the user to delete that entire row?

Edit:

```
def deleteRows(self):
    items = self.treeWidget.selectedItems()
    current = self.treeWidget.currentItem()
    for item in items:
        sip.delete(current)
        self.UpdateTree()
```

Edit 2:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from datetime import datetime



class DatabaseUtility: 
    def __init__(self, database, tableName):
        self.db = database
        self.tableName = tableName

    f = open('C:\\Users\\Vlad\\Desktop\\Myfiles\\EnterprisePassport\\password.txt', 'r')
    p = f.read(); f.close();
    self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root',
                                password = p,
                                host = '127.0.0.1')
    self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()

    self.ConnectToDatabase()
    self.CreateTable()

def ConnectToDatabase(self):
    try:
        self.cnx.database = self.db
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            self.CreateDatabase()
            self.cnx.database = self.db
        else:
            print(err.msg)

def CreateDatabase(self):
    try:
        self.RunCommand("CREATE DATABASE %s DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';" %self.db)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed creating database: {}".format(err))

def CreateTable(self):
    cmd = (" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + self.tableName + " ("
        " `ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
        " `date` date NOT NULL,"
        " `time` time NOT NULL,"
        " `message` char(50) NOT NULL,"
        " PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)"
        ") ENGINE=InnoDB;")
    self.RunCommand(cmd)

def GetTable(self):
    self.CreateTable()
    return self.RunCommand("SELECT * FROM %s;" % self.tableName)

def GetColumns(self):
    return self.RunCommand("SHOW COLUMNS FROM %s;" % self.tableName)

def RunCommand(self, cmd):
    print ("RUNNING COMMAND: " + cmd)
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(cmd)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print ('ERROR MESSAGE: ' + str(err.msg))
        print ('WITH ' + cmd)
    try:
        msg = self.cursor.fetchall()
    except:
        msg = self.cursor.fetchone()
    return msg

def AddEntryToTable(self, message):
    date1 = datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d")
    time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

    cmd = " INSERT INTO " + self.tableName + " (date, time, message)"
    cmd += " VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s' );" % (date1, time, message)
    self.RunCommand(cmd)

def __del__(self):
    self.cnx.commit()
    self.cursor.close()
    self.cnx.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = 'enterprisepassport'
    tableName = 'session'

    dbu = DatabaseUtility(db, tableName)
```

Comment: I suggest to create a delete button near the update button (or below the table) that deletes the selected rows when clicked, instead of adding a button for each row

Comment: For the user to select the rows I would have to create a check box of some sort or is it possible to just select the entire row by clicking on it?

Comment: Yuo can use setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows) for select the entire row with one click. Also consider setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection) to enable multiple selection (ctrl+click or shift+click)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a button at the top that deletes the selected rows.  It looks like your using a `QTreeWidget`

```
def __init__(...)
    ...
    self.deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteRows)

def deleteRows(self):
    items = self.tree.selectedItems()
    for item in items:
        # Code to delete items in database
    self.refreshTable()
```

Comment: Thank you, I am struggling now with the code for deleting the items and   the syntax for it. I am using Mysql for this table, and the code I have tried    is as follows: https://gyazo.com/6443b8b91c9828cdac8f7ac540cbe0a6 (Sorry for the URL, It doesn't seem to let me create a code block) And yet I still get an error either that there is no attribute "runCommand" or something of the sort.

Comment: def deleteRows(self):
        items = self.treeWidget.selectedItems()
        for item in items:
            self.RunCommand("DELETE FROM session %s;" % self.tableName)
            self.UpdateTree()                                                                                 (This is the code but like I said, It won't let me put it in a code block.)

Comment: What is `RunCommand`?  How are you connecting to the mysql database?  Are you using sqlalchemy?

Comment: I am using mysql connector through python to connect to my database. Using a piece of code that I found online, and modifying it to suit my program's needs, I found that the code uses self.runCommand when using SQL syntax. I've added the code that connects my program to the database in the question.

Comment: Update: I changed up the code a little bit in the question for deleting the item, however, now, nothing happens when I select and delete the row.

Answer (score -1):

@Randomator, why not explain as if you're explaining to a beginner. Even I do not also understand what you're suggesting.
The guy wrote his codes, make corrections in his code so he can easily run the file

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't think it's the answer to the question.